# Suma de matrices y valores relacionados con sus diagonales

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Debo hacer un programa para el cálculo de matriz:

Dándole por el teclado el tamaño de las matrices, introducir los valores de las matrices por teclado, para calcular:

1. La suma de dos martirices mostrando en pantalla las dos matrices que se introdujeron la A y la B y el resultado de la suma de las dos matrices A y B, Valor 5 Puntos.
2. Mostar en pantalla la diagonal segundaria de la matriz A, nada más los valores de la diagonal segundaria de la matriz A, Valor 5 Puntos.
3. Mostrar en pantalla ordenada de manera descendente la matriz resultante de la suma de la matriz A y matriz B, Valor 5 Puntos.
4. Mostrar en pantalla los valores por encima de la diagonal principal de la matriz que resulto de la suma de la matriz A y la matriz B,( nada mas los valores que están por encima de la diagonal), Valor 5 Puntos.

Para evaluar:

- Para que tenga valor el segundo tiene que correr el primero.
- Para que tenga valor el tercero tiene que correr el primero y el segundo.
- Para que tenga valor el cuarto tiene que correr el primero el segundo y el tercero.

Ya tengo la suma de matrices pero alguien que me pueda orientar en como hacer las otras partes

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int m,n, mayor=0, mat;
 cout<<"Suma de matrices mxn"<<endl;
 cout<<"Ingrese m: ";
 cin>>m;
 cout<<"Ingrese n: ";
 cin>>n;
 cout<<"***********"<<endl;
 int mat1[m][n], mat2[m][n];
 
 cout<<"Llenado de matriz 1"<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
   cout<<"Ingrese numero: ";
   cin>>mat1[i][j];
  }
 }
 cout<<"\n";
 cout<<"***********"<<endl;
 cout<<"Llenado de matriz 2"<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
   cout<<"Ingrese numero: ";
   cin>>mat2[i][j];
  }
 }
 cout<<"\n";
 cout<<"La matriz 1 es: "<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
   cout<<mat1[i][j]<<" ";
   
  }
  cout<<endl;
  
 }
 cout<<"\n";
 cout<<"La matriz dos es: "<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
   cout<<mat2[i][j]<<" ";
   
  }
  cout<<endl;
  
 }
 
 cout<<"\n";
 cout<<"La suma de las dos matrices es:"<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
   cout<<mat1[i][j]+mat2[i][j]<<" ";
   
   
  }
  cout<<endl;
  
 }
 
 
 

 return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, ayudaría que uses el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/455790/edit) y añadir el avance de código que tienes hasta ahorita, de lo contrario, se puede interpretar tu estancia aquí como que quieres que hagan la tarea por ti y esto no es muy bien visto en el sitio. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Haz que tu título sea descriptivo (al leer "tarea" difícilmente querrán responder). _¿Cuál es exactamente el problema que tienes?_ Además, no necesitamos saber que cada ítem vale 5 puntos :) Como te sugirieron anteriormente, lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para agregar las mejoras correspondientes.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es incorrecto ya en las primeras líneas de `main`. Utilizas Arreglos de Longitud Variable ([VLA en inglés [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), los cuáles no pertenecen al C++ estándar si no que son una extensión del compilador (Lee sobre la extensión en [el compilador GCC [image]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)). Cada compilador tiene sus propias extensiones de manera que es posible que este código te funcione en determinados compiladores.

Según el [estándar de C++ [image]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 8.3.4 Arreglos
>
> 1. En una declaración `T D` en que `D` tiene la forma
>
> **`D1 [` *expresión-constante*<sub>*opcional*</sub> `]` *secuencia-especificación-atributo*<sub>*opcional*</sub>**
>
> y el tipo del identificador en la declaración `T D1` es "*declarador-tipo-lista* `T`", entonces el tipo del identificador de `D` es arreglo; [...]

Este galimatías viene a decir que para crear un arreglo de la manera en que lo estás haciendo es imposible (sea de las dimensiones que sea), ya que los tamaños en la definición del array deben ser constantes conocidas en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n), pero el valor de `m` y `n` sólo se conoce en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n).

Para evitar estos problemas, mejor usa `std::vector`:

```
using Linea = std::vector<int>;
using Matriz = std::vector<Linea>;

// Matrices de 'm' lineas de 'n' columnas cada linea.
Matriz mat1(m, Linea(n, 0)), mat2(m, Linea(n, 0));
```

Para leer los datos, olvida los `for` indexados, usa `for` de rango y encapsula la lectura en una función:

```
void leer_matriz(Matriz &m)
{
    for (auto & linea : m)
        for (valor & linea)
        {
            std::cout << "Ingrese numero: ";
            std::cin >> valor;
        }
}
```

Para imprimir las matrices puedes sobrecargar el operador de inyección en flujo de datos, también puedes sobrecargar el operador de suma:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Matriz &m)
{
    for (const auto &linea : m)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : linea)
            o << valor << ' ';
        o << '\n';
    }

    return o;
}

Matriz operator+(const Matriz &m1, const Matriz &m2)
{
    Matriz resultado(m1);

    for (auto filas = m1.size(), fila = 0ul; fila != filas; ++fila)
    {
        for (auto columnas = m1[fila].size(), columna = 0ul; columna != columnas; ++columna)
            resultado[fila][columna] += m2[fila][columna];
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Eso te permitirá operaciones como esta:

```
std::cout << mat1 + mat2;
```

Las diagonales de la matriz son aquellas en que ambas coordenadas son iguales (fila = columna) o en que la suma de ambas coordenadas equivale al tamaño (fila + columna = mínimo de fila/columna), así que esto muestra las diagonales:

```
template <typename condicion>
void muestra_si(const Matriz &m, condicion c)
{
    for (auto filas = m.size(), fila = 0ul; fila != filas; ++fila)
    {
        for (auto columnas = m[fila].size(), columna = 0ul; columna != columnas; ++columna)
        {
            if (c(fila, columna)) std::cout << m[fila][columna];
            else std::cout << ' ';
            std::cout << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

// Diagonal principal
muestra_si(mat1, [](auto a, auto b) { return a == b; });
// Diagonal secundaria
muestra_si(mat1, [t = mat1.size() - 1](auto a, auto b) { return (a + b) == t; });
// Muestra los valores por encima de la diagonal principal
muestra_si(mat1, [](auto a, auto b) { return a <= b; });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPbjpswEH3GXzFVpQSEt0qy224bSL6g/YI0qrzESS35gsBE6iK@PR0bkwtZ9aX7xMyZM8fD8bgoy4dCMn04nT4KXchmxyEXprYVZ2pNLtiRF9ZU1wiTB1MJ@xtppKmFPsB3oTmDFdR2t1z2DbnQdp2F@g9mK/E6IvgmpBAPhpNhYkpeMVfP41GBQmF0bQe1iUpIS6K9qSDuC6yxBibSD7MELEdYvyccmURoCZ6IpCgykOfQwxhMYZqRAE5/apd0hEQVt02lwWQEszDDMGwaj0ab3w278NOGtOJ1Iy3bmVjNE7SgH9KPtxeS1WiVmn@qxSuPE@ohRGaNzPr4w6qnZZCmLrj@Uy9SGNkoHXQ2jrI9q4XaIDikqDl0OdkQe3vO0/ZKm1DbQoryixF469a51btmuSols7hD9k/JNVPcubQThTB6TY5G7EA1HC@c/arF2FJ64UJxufpb097Js/@1zClHYo97Fzuls0KS9E@gMI1166XuzYsiLmt@SwsbGb0FdmSMDyuLhuMjBMWEjr1fPsOfeKSg3cctXrBXMTtvW9zaBYXHjkL7ROEzhS8ufKbwlcK3DmOkLdoWs@dQQ86T6wDaYif2z7rOyV5do5OmsNn2LqMX/vuSQAthSdDYFbxk0OFTeKPTuhvBMFwHPMD8H2Ixg9QBKGnfSZJBfp6P3JrtRPA850t22foZbvvp9Bc)</kbd>.